# Any method for removing character from console in Java

Tags: java, char

I wrote following program but i want to remove "," from last element, what should i do?Is there any in-build method?

```
public class arraySort 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int a[]={2,7,5,6,9,8,4,3,1};
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<a.length;j++)
        {
            if(a[i]<a[j])
            {
                int temp;
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
            }               
        }
    }

    System.out.print("Descending order:{");
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    {
            System.out.print(a[i]+",");
    }
    System.out.println("}");

}
```

}

output:Descending order:{9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,}

Comment: If you change your printing logic for loop you won't need to remove the last ,

Comment: You can print the first element before the loop and start the loop with i = 1
    
    System.out.print(a[0]);
    for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.print("," + a[i]);
    }

Comment: @arseniyandru provided you also add a check for `a.length > 0`.

Comment: There's an easy if not very elegant ways to do it...  Add an if statement to the loop that's printing out the values...

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (i == a.length - 1)
            System.out.print(a[i]);
        else
            System.out.print(a[i] + ',');
    }

Have you thought about using a StringBuilder instead???

Comment: can't I simply put some method and erase last "," :)

Comment: I can change the logic to remove "," but i am searching if there is any method in java to erase the char.for example:- System.out.prinln(","); some function;      some function removes ","

Comment: No, you can't remove something from output stream.

Comment: ok thanks for help!!!

Answer (score -1):

or try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            int a[]={2,7,5,6,9,8,4,3,1};
            System.out.print("Descending order:{");
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1;j<a.length-1;j++)
                {
                    if(a[i]<a[j])
                    {
                        int temp;
                        temp=a[i];
                        a[i]=a[j];
                        a[j]=temp;
                    }
                }
                if (i == a.length-1) {
                    System.out.print(a[i]);
                } else {
                     System.out.print(a[i]+",");
                }
            }
        System.out.println("}");
    }
```

Comment: i get it but i want to know if there is such type of method is exist in java or not? Thanks for help

Comment: answer is "NO".
you will either need to store the result in a string and then using String's `lastIndexOf` method, remove last occurrence of ",".